# Unable to retrieve vector data types with GeoServer REST API

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I am currently working on a project where I need to retrieve data types (e.g., Point, Line, Polygon) using the GeoServer REST API. I've explored the GetCapabilities link, but unfortunately, I couldn't find any information regarding data type details.

I came across an endpoint, but it seems to provide data in Java types, making it challenging to interpret. Location of this info is "GEOSERVER_URL/geoserver/rest/workspaces/public/datastores/apotheken/featuretypes/layer_name.json
Here is the JSON object I've been working with:

```
    const geometryJSON = {
  "org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point": "circle",
  "org.locationtech.jts.geom.MultiPoint": "circle",
  "org.locationtech.jts.geom.LineString": "line",
  "org.locationtech.jts.geom.LinearRing": "line",
  "org.locationtech.jts.geom.MultiLineString": "line",
  "org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon": "fill",
  "org.locationtech.jts.geom.MultiPolygon": "fill",
  // "org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryCollection": geometryCollectionGeometry,
  // it means that the geometry type is mixed (point, line, polygon)
  // we don't need to handle this case, because we are only interested in the geometry type of the first feature
};
```

Is there a straightforward way to obtain the actual data types (e.g., Point, Line, Polygon) using GeoServer REST API? Any guidance on how to interpret the Java types or any alternative approaches?

Comment: Use the WFS describeFeature endpoint. But why do you need to know what the geometry type is?

Comment: We use data with Maplibre so we need to write type of vector data for visualization. I also offered to reach endpoint which I share in my question, read last object and then understand what type of object but we don't think it's good method.
sample endpoint:


[
{"name":"geom","minOccurs":0,"maxOccurs":1,"nillable":true,"binding":"org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point"},
{"name":"gemeinde","minOccurs":0,"maxOccurs":1,"nillable":true,"binding":"java.lang.String"},
{"name":"name","minOccurs":0,"maxOccurs":1,"nillable":true,"binding":"java.lang.String"}
]